# Get on top of the select option a specific value

Tags: javascript

I have this form here:

```
<form action="listasearch.php" method="get">
<select name="kategoria">
  <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
  <option value="id">ID</option>
  <option value="dyqani_pergjegjes">Dyqani Përgjegjës</option>
  <option value="emri">Emri</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

Now, i also have a $kategoria php value that holds the selected value.
I'd need a javascript in order I.e , if $kategoria=id in the form the

```
<option value="id">ID</option>
```

should come first..
Someone help please!

Comment: Do you mean that the ID option in this case should be selected in the dropdown menu? Or that the ID option should be moved first in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr("value") == "<?php echo $kategoria; ?>"; 
    }).prop('selected', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class to you select, example test

```
$('.test').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() === 'Untagged') {
//get the selected option
var option = jQuery(this);
//remove that option
$(this).remove();
//put it on top
 $('.test').prepend(option);
  }
});
```